# osCommerce Meta tag include from database

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta, oscommerce

There is no default meta tag in my template. So I have added this meta tag:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo tep_output_string_protected($oscTemplate->getTitle()); ?>,AADVR Systems from ECCS" />
```

But my problem is in the meta description portion:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="***Here I want to add description from my Product description***" />
```

How can I add: `<?php echo tep_output_string_protected($oscTemplate->getTitle()); ?>`

Comment: as a sample you can see my site: [link] (http://www.aadvr.com) [link] where is my problem.

Comment: Googling `oscommerce get product description` seems to show that the method you are looking for is named `tep_get_products_description`. That's worth checking out

Answer (score 0):

In osCommerce you have

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>"
```

line of code in `includes/template_top.php`

There is no code for Meta tag description but there are few contributions to choose from:

- [Easy Meta tags](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/5497)
- [Modular SEO Header Tags](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/7646/v,23)
- [Header Tags Controller By Jack Mcs (recommended)](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/207)